# ASP.Net Webforms + MVC - Working except for Postbacks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've been following some articles on combining ASP.Net Webforms + MVC ('Hybrid' ASP.Net site) in order to migrate one of our legacy web apps.  I think I've managed to get most of the functionality in place in the migrated app, but I've found that controls such as gridviews lose their state when I post back (using ASP.Net ajax as well at this point).

Code is roughly as follows when a user clicks 'edit' on a row:

```
public int GetActivityTypeId(int index)
{
    // Get the row data from the grid
    GridViewRow row = GrdContent.Rows[index]; << Rows is 0 in Hybrid app, works pre-conversion

    // Cell 0 is the Id
    return int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
}
```

Control is configured as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GrdContent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AllowPaging="false" CssClass="GridViewStyle" OnRowDeleting="GrdContentRowDeleting"
             OnRowEditing="GrdContentRowEditing" OnRowDataBound="GrdContentRowDataBound">
            <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewFooterStyle" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridViewSelectedRowStyle" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
            <Columns>             
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Activity Type Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentActivityTypeName" HeaderText="Activity Type Parent" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Link" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <ctl:CustomPager ID="PgrCustom" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="PgrCustomPageIndexChanging" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnModalOkay" EventName="click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnFilter" EventName="click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The legacy code follows a MVP pattern.

I'm using the following articles for the conversion:

- [Mixing ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)
- [Plug-In Hybrids: ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx)
- [Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use controls that rely on state in ASP.NET MVC applications, there's no 'view state' in ASP.NET MVC, so server side controls will not remember their state between postbacks.

Check out jqGrid for a jQuery library for creating cool grids.

Comment: That's what I assumed from researching similar questions, but Scott Hanselman's blog post (linked above) states a single web application containing mixed technologies is possible? It's the 2nd link.

Comment: You can mix technologies in the same project, but not on the same page (although I'm not sure if that's what you're doing here).

Comment: Hi Mike, nope not same page! Might be a configuration issue but I've combed through web.config a few times... tried to find an example on the web of this type of project but came up short.